# TypeScript 0.9.1.1 Not Always Compiling On Save

Tags: typescript

using VS 2012 Update 3,  TSC 0.9.1.1., and the latest version of Web Essentials (although this has been a problem since Web Essentials removed support for TypeScript).

Very often TypeScript will not compile on save. I've had to resort to having the .js file open at the same time, and hope that I get the message about a file changing. But then all of a sudden it will stop building, and thus the file doesn't get changed and I don't see the message.

Sometimes it appears to be a problem with erroneous errors that TypeScript is generating, which I know they are because usually removing a ";" and adding it back will usually make it re-think it's error and remove it. The error doesn't even have to be on that file, and fixing the error never fixes the save & compile "feature".

The only "fix" I have found is to close the .ts file, and .js file (.js file is important). Then open the .ts, wait for it to fully load, and then load the .js file, in that order, or it will never work (you don't have to open the .js file, but if you open it first it won't work).

I've tried restarting (VS and Win 7) and that will fix it for awhile, but eventually and again often it will stop working.

This is very annoying as I'm writing TypeScript the vast majority of the day.

Answer (score 1):

I authored grunt-ts to do our typescript compilation which works reliably every time : https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-ts

Check out the video tutorial : http://youtu.be/Km0DpfX5ZxM

Answer (score 1):

I find that doing a project compile (cs/vb) is required to generate the initial .js file. After that, the typescript compile on save works properly.

Comment: When I added support for generating .js on build if there was any error it would take a very long time for VS to become responsive. If there were no errors it is very fast. I have had to take it out, because at this point I'm having problems with TFS build not working with TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade your csproj file of the visual studio project manually.
I had to include the following lines to have compile on save functionality working again.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
<TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
<TypeScriptIncludeComments>true</TypeScriptIncludeComments>
<TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
<TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
<TypeScriptIncludeComments>false</TypeScriptIncludeComments>
<TypeScriptSourceMap>false</TypeScriptSourceMap>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />
```

Additinaly, I had to save most of my .ts-Files and setting the file encoding to codepage 65001.

Answer (score 0):

Try following these instructions, ensuring each of your TypeScript files have their build action set to **TypeScriptCompile**.

[Compile-on-Save](http://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Compile-on-Save)

Also see my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20531258/295813) for my take on some of the suspected confusion with the TypeScript support.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it sufficed to close any application (in my case notepad++) that accessed the javascript file, and then reopen the javascript files again. I didn't need to quit Visual Studio or close and reopen any of the Typescript files inside of Visual Studio.

I'm running VS Express 2013 for Web update 2 RC.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by right-click on the typescript file and setting the BuildAction to None.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, typescript compiles would just not work at all after doing about two hours of debugging a program.  Rebooting the system didn't help, restarting Visual Studio didn't help.  What finally worked for me is removing the tool named "Web Essentials"